# python - jquery datatables with mongodb(mongoengine)

Tags: python, mongodb, datatables, pyramid, mongoengine

I am new to Python, MongoDB(mongoengine(ODM)) and the pyramid framework as a whole. I am currently working on a project using the above mentioned technologies and I want to use [jQuery datatables](http://datatables.net)(also new to this) I found a link on their site on how to use [datatables with MongoDB](http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mongodb), but it is in php and my translation skills aren't that good.

**my question is:** 
 
Is it possible to use datatables using the above mentioned technologies, if yes, then how?

I have tried converting someone else's code that used SQLAlchemy with datatables, but I am stuck as I do not know how to change the function.

```
@view_config(
route_name='candidate.list.json',
renderer='json',
permission="admin"
)

def candidate_list_json(context, request):
    def format_output(vals):
        vals = list(vals)
        vals[-1] = """<div class="btn-group"><a href='%s' class=btn>View</a><a href='%s' class=btn>Edit</a></div>""" % (
            request.route_url('candidates', id_number=vals[-1], traverse=()),
            request.route_url('candidates', id_number=vals[-1], traverse="edit")
        )
        vals[0] = "<a href='%s'>%s</a>" % (request.route_url('candidates', id_number=vals[0], traverse=()), vals[0])
        return vals
    if has_permission('admin', context, request):
        basefilt = None                  # I changed Up to here
    return handle_datatable(
        request,
        Agents.id,
        [Agents.db_agent_id, Agents.db_name, Agents.id_number, Agents.mobile_number, OrgUnits.name, Agents.db_agent_id],
        lambda term: or_(Agents.db_agent_name.like('%'+term+'%'), OrgUnits.name.like('%'+term+'%'), Agents.mobile_number.like('%'+term+'%'), Agents.id_number.like('%'+term+'%'), ),
        join=[Agents.ou],
        formatfunc=format_output,
        base_filt=basefilt
    )
```

`handle_datatable` is a method:

```
def handle_datatable(request, idcol, cols, filtfunc, options=None, cache='short_term', formatfunc=None, displaylength=90, join=None, base_filt=None, outerjoin=None, groupby=None, no_paginate=False, ordercols=None, orderby=None, printquery=False, nocount=False):
s = sqlahelper.get_session()
if groupby is not None and type(groupby) != list and type(groupby) != tuple:
    groupby = [groupby]

def attachfilt(q, filt, nogroup=False):
    if filt:
        q = q.filter(and_(*filt))
    if join:
        q = q.join(*join)
    if outerjoin:
        q = q.outerjoin(*outerjoin)
    if options:
        q = q.options(*options)
    if groupby and not nogroup:
        for g in groupby:
            q = q.group_by(g)
    return q

@cache_region('short_term')
def perform_count(filt, idcol, term):
    if not nocount:
        return attachfilt(s.query(idcol), filt, nogroup=False).count()
    else:
        return 0

#@cache_region('short_term', 'handle_search')
def perform_search(filt, cols, iStart, iLength, order_cols):
    q = attachfilt(s.query(*cols), filt)
    if order_cols:
        q = q.order_by(*order_cols)

    if printquery:
        print q
    if no_paginate:
        rows = q.all()
    else:
        rows = q[iStart:iStart+iLength]
    if callable(formatfunc):
        data = [formatfunc(row[:]) for row in rows]
    else:
        data = [row[:] for row in rows]
    return data

if not callable(filtfunc):
    raise Exception("Filter Function is not callable")
if not cols:
    raise Exception("Please provide columns to search")

if not no_paginate:
    iStart = int(str(request.params.get("iDisplayStart", 0)))
    iLength = int(str(request.params.get("iDisplayLength", displaylength)))
else:
    iStart = 0
    iLength = 0

if not ordercols:
    ordercols = cols

if orderby:
    order_cols = orderby
else:
    order_cols = []
if request.params.get("iSortCol_0", None):
    iSortingCols = int(str(request.params.get('iSortingCols', 0)))
    for k in range(0, iSortingCols):
        iSortCol = int(str(request.params.get('iSortCol_%s' % k, 0)))
        sSortDir = str(request.params.get('sSortDir_%s' % k, 0))
        if str(request.params.get('bSortable_%s' % iSortCol, 'false') == 'true'):
            col = ordercols[iSortCol]
            if sSortDir == "asc":
                order_cols.append(col.asc())
            else:
                order_cols.append(col.desc())
search = request.params.get("sSearch", None)
filt = []
if search:
    filt = filtfunc(search)
if filt is not None and type(filt) != list:
    filt = [filt]
if type(cols) != list:
    cols = [cols]


itotal = perform_count([base_filt], idcol, search)
if no_paginate:
    iLength = itotal
if base_filt is not None:
    filt.append(base_filt)
cnt = perform_count(filt, idcol, search)
data = perform_search(filt, cols, iStart, iLength, order_cols)

return dict(
    sEcho=request.params.get("sEcho", 0),
    iTotalRecords=itotal,
    iTotalDisplayRecords=cnt,
    aaData=data
)
```

As I said before I am new to these Technologies, but I am willing to learn, if you can just point me in the right direction.

---

**UPDATE:**

So now I got this code:

```
import pymongo
from pyramid_mongo import get_db

# translation for sorting between datatables api and mongodb
order_dict = {'asc': 1, 'desc': -1}


class DataTables_Handler(object):
    def __init__(self, request, columns, index, collection):
        self.columns = columns
        self.index = index
        self.db = get_db(request)
        self.collection = collection

        # values specified by the datatable for filtering, sorting, paging
        self.request_values = request.params

        # results from the db
        self.result_data = None

        # total in the table after filtering
        self.cardinality_filtered = 0

        # total in the table unfiltered
        self.cadinality = 0

        self.run_queries()

    def output_result(self):
        output = {}
        output['sEcho'] = str(int(self.request_values['sEcho']))
        output['iTotalRecords'] = str(self.cardinality)
        output['iTotalDisplayRecords'] = str(self.cardinality_filtered)
        aaData_rows = []

        for row in self.result_data:
            aaData_row = []
            for i in range(len(self.columns)):

                aaData_row.append(row[self.columns[i]].replace('"', '\\"'))

            # add additional rows here that are not represented in the database
            # aaData_row.append(('''<input id='%s' type='checkbox'></input>''' % (str(row[ self.index ]))).replace('\\', ''))

            aaData_rows.append(aaData_row)

        output['aaData'] = aaData_rows

        return output

    def run_queries(self):

        # pages has 'start' and 'length' attributes
        pages = self.paging()

        # the term you entered into the datatable search
        filters = self.filtering()

        # the document field you chose to sort
        sorting = self.sorting()

        # get result from db
        self.result_data = self.db.self.collection.find(spec=filters,
                                                      skip=pages.start,
                                                      limit=pages.length,
                                                      sort=sorting)

        total_count = len(list(self.db.self.collection.find(spec=filters)))

        self.result_data = list(self.result_data)

        self.cardinality_filtered = total_count

        self.cardinality = len(list(self.db.self.collection.find()))

    def filtering(self):

        # build your filter spec
        filters = {}
        if (self.request_values.has_key('sSearch')) and (self.request_values['sSearch'] != ""):

            # the term put into search is logically concatenated with 'or' between all columns
        or_filter_on_all_columns = []

            for i in range(len(self.columns)):
                column_filter = {}
                column_filter[self.columns[i]] = {'$regex': self.request_values['sSearch'], '$options': 'i'}
                or_filter_on_all_columns.append(column_filter)
            filters['$or'] = or_filter_on_all_columns
        return filters

    def sorting(self):
        order = []
        # mongo translation for sorting order

        if (self.request_values['iSortCol_0'] != "") and (self.request_values['iSortingCols'] > 0):
            order = []
            for i in range(int(self.request_values['iSortingCols'])):
                order.append((self.columns[int(self.request_values['iSortCol_' + str(i)])], order_dict[self.request_values['sSortDir_' + str(i)]]))
        return order

    def paging(self):
        pages = namedtuple('pages', ['start', 'length'])
        if (self.request_values['iDisplayStart'] != "") and (self.request_values['iDisplayLength'] != -1):
            pages.start = int(self.request_values['iDisplayStart'])
            pages.length = int(self.request_values['iDisplayLength'])
        return pages
```

with this code in the View:

```
@view_config(
route_name='candidates.list.json',
renderer='json',
permission='admin'
)
def candidate_list_json(context, request):
    columns = [ 'id_number', 'first_name', 'email', 'mobile_number']
    index_column = "id_number"
    collection = "candidates"

    results = DataTables_Handler(request, columns, index_column, collection).output_result()

    # return the results as a string for the datatable
    return {"results": results}
```

and this in the template:

```
<a id="btn-addteam" class="btn btn-success" href="{{'add_candidate'|route_url}}"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Add Candidate</a>
```

ID Number
            Candidate Name
            Candidate email
            Mobile Number
            Health -->

```
<script src="{{'kivu:static/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js'|static_url}}"></script>
    <script src="{{'kivu:static/datatables/dataTables.scroller.js'|static_url}}"></script>   
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    url = "{{'candidates.list.json'|route_url}}";
    var oTable = $('#candidate_search').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bjQueryUI": true,
        "sAjaxSource": url
});
} );</script>
```

But its giving me a js error:

```
TypeError: aData is undefined
    for ( var i=0, iLen=aData.length ; i<iLen ; i++ )
```

my GET response  returns:

```
{"results": {"aaData": [], "iTotalRecords": "0", "sEcho": "1", "iTotalDisplayRecords": "0"}}
```

there is data in the database. What am I missing? I hope this update isn't off topic...

Comment: For jQuery DataTables plugin, please use [datatables] tag.

Comment: I have updated my  question with the correct tag... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible to use jQuery Datatables using your mentioned technologies. Pyramid is handling requests and manages database connection, processes requests into queries and assembles any query results or other data into a Response or return data that is given to renderers supporting templates written in Chameleon or Mako. You add jQuery DataTables to your templates - that's it from a bird's-eye view.

You have at least 2 ways to pass data to DataTables

1. assemble query results in a view, return data to a renderer using a chameleon template (http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/quick_tutorial/templating.html), use TAL to iterate over your data and generate valid DataTables HTML as shown in DataTables docs
2. if you finished version 1 switching to AJAX could be an option for you. Then you create DataTables markup in Javascript and use a Pyramid JSON renderer to return a JSON response to your AJAX client most probably using jQuery. (http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/quick_tutorial/json.html)

Your example is mixing up too much concerns and fails because of complexity. Take any official pyramid tutorial - you will hardly find any snippet that is that difficult to read and understand. Yours is difficult to read and understand - at least for me. Besides that it is not testable in any way. Pyramid starters should follow the development style shown. Pyramid really makes Unit & Functional Testing easy.

Follow this tutorial - it is worth the time: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/quick_tutorial/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your response... it has been help full in a way. I got something that kind of works... See update.

Comment: got it right... see my answer.. I accepted you answer, because it got me to a point where I could modify the code that I did. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

so I got it to work: I modified this [script](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/13679/working-code-for-server-side-paging-filtering-sorting-for-python-flask-mongodb/p1#Form_Comment):

I created a module called tools and in the `__init__.py`:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import pymongo


# translation for sorting between datatables api and mongodb
order_dict = {'asc': 1, 'desc': -1}


class DataTables_Handler(object):
    def __init__(self, request, columns, index, collection):
        self.columns = columns
        self.index = index
        #self.db = get_db(request)
        self.collection = collection

        # values specified by the datatable for filtering, sorting, paging
        self.request_values = request.params

        self.db = pymongo.MongoClient()

        # results from the db
        self.result_data = None

        # total in the table after filtering
        self.cardinality_filtered = 0

        # total in the table unfiltered
        self.cadinality = 0

        self.run_queries()

    def output_result(self):
        output = {}
        output['sEcho'] = str(int(self.request_values['sEcho']))
        output['iTotalRecords'] = str(self.cardinality)
        output['iTotalDisplayRecords'] = str(self.cardinality_filtered)
        aaData_rows = []
        #print "sEcho", output['sEcho']

        for row in self.result_data:
            print row
            aaData_row = []
            for i in range(len(self.columns)):

                aaData_row.append(row[self.columns[i]])
                #print aData_row
            #add additional rows here that are not represented in the database
            aaData_row.append(('''<input id='%s' type='checkbox'></input>''' % (str(row[ self.index ]))).replace('\\', ''))

            aaData_rows.append(aaData_row)

        output['aaData'] = aaData_rows
        print "output: ", output
        return output

    def run_queries(self):
        #call db
        db = self.db.mydb

        # pages has 'start' and 'length' attributes
        pages = self.paging()

        # the term you entered into the datatable search
        filters = self.filtering()

        # the document field you chose to sort
        sorting = self.sorting()

        # get result from db
        self.result_data = db[self.collection].find(spec=filters,
                                                  skip=pages.start,
                                                  limit=pages.length,
                                                  sort=sorting)

        total_count = len(list(db[self.collection].find(spec=filters)))

        self.result_data = list(self.result_data)
        print "result_data", self.result_data

        self.cardinality_filtered = total_count

        self.cardinality = len(list(db[self.collection].find()))
        print "cardinality", self.cardinality

    def filtering(self):

        # build your filter spec
        filters = {}
        if ('sSearch' in self.request_values.keys()) and (self.request_values['sSearch'] != ""):

            # the term put into search is logically concatenated with 'or' between all columns
            or_filter_on_all_columns = []

            for i in range(len(self.columns)):
                column_filter = {}
                column_filter[self.columns[i]] = {'$regex':     self.request_values['sSearch'], '$options': 'i'}
            or_filter_on_all_columns.append(column_filter)
            filters['$or'] = or_filter_on_all_columns
        return filters

    def sorting(self):
        order = []
        # mongo translation for sorting order

        if (self.request_values['iSortCol_0'] != "") and (self.request_values['iSortingCols'] > 0):
            order = []
            for i in range(int(self.request_values['iSortingCols'])):
                order.append((self.columns[int(self.request_values['iSortCol_' + str(i)])], order_dict[self.request_values['sSortDir_' + str(i)]]))
        return order

    def paging(self):
        pages = namedtuple('pages', ['start', 'length'])
        if (self.request_values['iDisplayStart'] != "") and (self.request_values['iDisplayLength'] != -1):
            pages.start = int(self.request_values['iDisplayStart'])
            pages.length = int(self.request_values['iDisplayLength'])
        return pages
```

and in my `View.py` I have:

```
@view_config(
route_name='candidates.list.json',
renderer='json',
permission='admin'
)
def candidate_list_json(context, request):
    columns = [ '_id', 'first_name', 'email', 'mobile_number']
    index_column = "_id"
    collection = "candidates"

    results = DataTables_Handler(request, columns, index_column, collection).output_result()
    print "Results:   ", results
    # return the results as a string for the datatable
    return results
```

and then In my template I have:

```
<script src="{{'kivu:static/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js'|static_url}}"></script>
    <script src="{{'kivu:static/datatables/dataTables.scroller.js'|static_url}}"></script>   
<script>
    url = "{{'candidates.list.json'|route_url}}";
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#candidate_search').dataTable( {
        "sScrollY": "425px",
       // "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sAjaxSource": url,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sDom": "<'row'<'col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6'><'col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6'i><'col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6'>>S",
        //"sDom": "frtiS",
        //"sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "bProcessing" : true, 
       // "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 5 ] }],
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "bStateSave": true
    } );
console.log(oTable);
        $.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
            "sSortAsc": "header headerSortDown",
            "sSortDesc": "header headerSortUp",
            "sSortable": "header"
        } );
        $.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
            "sWrapper": "dataTables_wrapper form-inline"
        } );
    } );</script>
```

I hope this can help someone, as `class DataTables_Handler` is re-useable.